# 'RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded' when training with QuantumKernelTrainer inside a QisKit IBM Runtime Session

Tags: python, quantum-computing, qiskit

I am encountering a `RecursionError` when using the [`QuantumKernelTrainer` class](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-machine-learning/blob/5abda6c0fd303453229f9caabcd831de792fdd75/qiskit_machine_learning/kernels/algorithms/quantum_kernel_trainer.py) during the fitting process of a [`TrainableFidelityQuantumKernel` object](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-machine-learning/blob/5abda6c0fd303453229f9caabcd831de792fdd75/qiskit_machine_learning/kernels/trainable_fidelity_quantum_kernel.py) from the [`qiskit_machine_learning` package](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-machine-learning.git) within a Qiskit IBM Runtime session. To train the classifier over a noisy backend, I am manually setting a noise model in the `Sampler` options.

However, the traceback reveals that the issue is related to the `deepcopy` function in the `copy` module, which is called by the internal functions of the `QuantumKernelTrainer`.

I want to know if the issue I'm facing is due to a bug in the underlying code or if the approach I'm taking is incorrect. Can you help me figure this out?

This is a minimal working example to prompt the error:

```
from qiskit.algorithms.optimizers import SLSQP
from qiskit.algorithms.state_fidelities import ComputeUncompute
from qiskit.circuit.library import TwoLocal
from qiskit.providers.fake_provider import FakeBackendV2
from qiskit.utils import algorithm_globals
from qiskit_aer.noise import NoiseModel
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService, Options, Session, Sampler
from qiskit_machine_learning.kernels import TrainableFidelityQuantumKernel
from qiskit_machine_learning.kernels.algorithms import QuantumKernelTrainer
import numpy as np
seed=2023

algorithm_globals.random_seed = seed # Reproducibility purposes
rand = algorithm_globals.random.uniform

#Define a feature_map
ansatz = TwoLocal(
    num_qubits=2,
    rotation_blocks=['rz','ry'],
    entanglement_blocks='cx',
    reps=1)

#Random data set (4 features, 5 items)
rand = algorithm_globals.random.uniform
x_train = rand(0,2*np.pi,(5,4))
y_train = np.heaviside(rand(-1,1,5),0)

#Load QiskitRuntime Account
service = QiskitRuntimeService()

#Retrieve qasm_simulator
backend = service.backends(simulator=True)[0]

noise_model = NoiseModel.from_backend(FakeBackendV2())
options_noise = {
    'simulator': {
        "noise_model": noise_model,
        "seed_simulator": seed
    },
    'resilience_level': 0
}

with Session(service=service, backend=backend):

    # Define a trainable kernel (last 4 parameters for training)
    TFQK = TrainableFidelityQuantumKernel(
        feature_map = ansatz,
        fidelity = ComputeUncompute(
            sampler=Sampler(options=options_noise)
        ),
        training_parameters = ansatz.parameters[4:8]
    )

    # Define quantum kernel trainer
    QKT = QuantumKernelTrainer(
        quantum_kernel=TFQK,
        optimizer=SLSQP(maxiter=1000)
    )

    # Fit the quantum kernel
    # This line prompts the error
    QKT.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

The error obtained is the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 56
     49 QKT = QuantumKernelTrainer(
     50     quantum_kernel=TFQK,
     51     optimizer=SLSQP(maxiter=1000)
     52 )
     54 # Fit the quantum kernel
     55 # This line prompts the error
---> 56 QKT.fit(x_train,y_train)

File .../conda/envs/QC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit_machine_learning/kernels/algorithms/quantum_kernel_trainer.py:202, in QuantumKernelTrainer.fit(self, data, labels)
    199     raise ValueError(msg)
    201 # Bind inputs to objective function
--> 202 output_kernel = copy.deepcopy(self._quantum_kernel)
    204 # Randomly initialize the initial point if one was not passed
    205 if self._initial_point is None:

File .../conda/envs/QC/lib/python3.9/copy.py:172, in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    170                 y = x
    171             else:
--> 172                 y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
    174 # If is its own copy, don't memoize.
    175 if y is not x:

File .../conda/envs/QC/lib/python3.9/copy.py:270, in _reconstruct(x, memo, func, args, state, listiter, dictiter, deepcopy)
    268 if state is not None:
    269     if deep:
--> 270         state = deepcopy(state, memo)
    271     if hasattr(y, '__setstate__'):
    272         y.__setstate__(state)

File .../conda/envs/QC/lib/python3.9/copy.py:146, in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    144 copier = _deepcopy_dispatch.get(cls)
    145 if copier is not None:
--> 146     y = copier(x, memo)
    147 else:
    148     if issubclass(cls, type):

File .../conda/envs/QC/lib/python3.9/copy.py:230, in _deepcopy_dict(x, memo, deepcopy)
    228 memo[id(x)] = y
    229 for key, value in x.items():
--> 230     y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
    231 return y

File .../conda/envs/QC/lib/python3.9/copy.py:172, in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    170                 y = x
    171             else:
--> 172                 y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
    174 # If is its own copy, don't memoize.
    175 if y is not x:

File .../conda/envs/QC/lib/python3.9/copy.py:270, in _reconstruct(x, memo, func, args, state, listiter, dictiter, deepcopy)
    268 if state is not None:
    269     if deep:
--> 270         state = deepcopy(state, memo)
    271     if hasattr(y, '__setstate__'):
    272         y.__setstate__(state)

File .../conda/envs/QC/lib/python3.9/copy.py:146, in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    144 copier = _deepcopy_dispatch.get(cls)
    145 if copier is not None:
--> 146     y = copier(x, memo)
    147 else:
    148     if issubclass(cls, type):

File .../conda/envs/QC/lib/python3.9/copy.py:230, in _deepcopy_dict(x, memo, deepcopy)
    228 memo[id(x)] = y
    229 for key, value in x.items():
--> 230     y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
    231 return y

    [... skipping similar frames: deepcopy at line 172 (3 times), _deepcopy_dict at line 230 (2 times), _reconstruct at line 270 (2 times), deepcopy at line 146 (2 times)]

File .../conda/envs/QC/lib/python3.9/copy.py:270, in _reconstruct(x, memo, func, args, state, listiter, dictiter, deepcopy)
    268 if state is not None:
    269     if deep:
--> 270         state = deepcopy(state, memo)
    271     if hasattr(y, '__setstate__'):
    272         y.__setstate__(state)

    [... skipping similar frames: _deepcopy_dict at line 230 (1 times), deepcopy at line 146 (1 times)]

File .../conda/envs/QC/lib/python3.9/copy.py:146, in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    144 copier = _deepcopy_dispatch.get(cls)
    145 if copier is not None:
--> 146     y = copier(x, memo)
    147 else:
    148     if issubclass(cls, type):

File .../conda/envs/QC/lib/python3.9/copy.py:230, in _deepcopy_dict(x, memo, deepcopy)
    228 memo[id(x)] = y
    229 for key, value in x.items():
--> 230     y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
    231 return y

File .../conda/envs/QC/lib/python3.9/copy.py:172, in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    170                 y = x
    171             else:
--> 172                 y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
    174 # If is its own copy, don't memoize.
    175 if y is not x:

File .../conda/envs/QC/lib/python3.9/copy.py:271, in _reconstruct(x, memo, func, args, state, listiter, dictiter, deepcopy)
    269 if deep:
    270     state = deepcopy(state, memo)
--> 271 if hasattr(y, '__setstate__'):
    272     y.__setstate__(state)
    273 else:

File .../conda/envs/QC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit_ibm_runtime/ibm_backend.py:196, in IBMBackend.__getattr__(self, name)
    190 """Gets attribute from self or configuration
    191 
    192 This magic method executes when user accesses an attribute that
    193 does not yet exist on IBMBackend class.
    194 """
    195 # Lazy load properties and pulse defaults and construct the target object.
--> 196 self._get_properties()
    197 self._get_defaults()
    198 self._convert_to_target()

File .../conda/envs/QC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit_ibm_runtime/ibm_backend.py:217, in IBMBackend._get_properties(self)
    215 def _get_properties(self) -> None:
    216     """Gets backend properties and decodes it"""
--> 217     if not self._properties:
    218         api_properties = self._api_client.backend_properties(self.name)
    219         if api_properties:

File .../conda/envs/QC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit_ibm_runtime/ibm_backend.py:196, in IBMBackend.__getattr__(self, name)
    190 """Gets attribute from self or configuration
    191 
    192 This magic method executes when user accesses an attribute that
    193 does not yet exist on IBMBackend class.
    194 """
    195 # Lazy load properties and pulse defaults and construct the target object.
--> 196 self._get_properties()
    197 self._get_defaults()
    198 self._convert_to_target()

File .../conda/envs/QC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit_ibm_runtime/ibm_backend.py:217, in IBMBackend._get_properties(self)
    215 def _get_properties(self) -> None:
    216     """Gets backend properties and decodes it"""
--> 217     if not self._properties:
    218         api_properties = self._api_client.backend_properties(self.name)
    219         if api_properties:

    [... skipping similar frames: IBMBackend.__getattr__ at line 196 (1471 times), IBMBackend._get_properties at line 217 (1470 times)]

File .../conda/envs/QC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit_ibm_runtime/ibm_backend.py:217, in IBMBackend._get_properties(self)
    215 def _get_properties(self) -> None:
    216     """Gets backend properties and decodes it"""
--> 217     if not self._properties:
    218         api_properties = self._api_client.backend_properties(self.name)
    219         if api_properties:

File .../conda/envs/QC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit_ibm_runtime/ibm_backend.py:196, in IBMBackend.__getattr__(self, name)
    190 """Gets attribute from self or configuration
    191 
    192 This magic method executes when user accesses an attribute that
    193 does not yet exist on IBMBackend class.
    194 """
    195 # Lazy load properties and pulse defaults and construct the target object.
--> 196 self._get_properties()
    197 self._get_defaults()
    198 self._convert_to_target()

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: As this seems very specific to Qiskit IBM Runtime I would suggest raising this an issue there https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ibm-runtime/issues

Comment: Done! https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ibm-runtime/issues/745